# System Restore problem

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, restore, system-restore, windows-7-restore

I'm looking for System Restore software for my company. I want software that can run on multiple systems, around ten Windows 7 machines.

Can anyone suggest something good and affordable?

Comment: Can you tell more about the configuration or how it will be used?

Comment: @Ivo Flipse does this not count as a shopping rec?

Comment: "System Restore software"? Do you mean you want system repair discs? If so, you can make them yourself (if you have a way to burn discs), or sometimes you can request them from the hardware vendor.

Answer (score 1):

You are really looking for a corporate IT backup policy. If you are asking here and do not have an internal IT support team, I would highly recommend that you consult a local firm / consider how important IT is to your business.

There are many solutions depending on your budget.

The cheapest would be to buy an external USB drive and manually taking images of every machine and save to that.

Next would be a central NAS unit and do imaging again.

Consider also a NAS in combination with [Cobian Backup](http://www.educ.umu.se/~cobian/cobianbackup.htm) (A very flexible backup solution).

Next up, if you do not have a domain and it is just a collection of computers on a workgroup, consider Windows Home Server.

After this, you start getting in to serious money - so if you want some other solutions, please say what is most important to you? Ensuring minimum down time/restoring computers or restoring computers to when you took the backup, or just backing up files regularly.

Comment: And, if you are in the UK, I offer this sort of service to clients. Feel free to look at my profile and give me an email!